# How to change the request's path in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a REST AWS API Gateway that has a `foo` resources that is accessible via GETs. e.g. you can access it via the url `https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stageName/foo`. This is forwarded to a VPC link which forwards to a kubernetes pod running a rails application.

When I make the GET request, it successfully arrives at the rails pod, but the request's path is just `/` which is not what I want. How do I rewrite the requests path to be `/foo`? I've found a lot of stuff about rewriting the body of the request, but I haven't found anything about rewriting the path.

Comment: When you've configured `/foo` response to some other aws service, you don't need to check if it's from `/foo` as it's the only source you'll get traffic from, but if you've configured `/{proxy+}` then you need to handle the path based response handling.